# Android Custom shape ImageView: Zoom In/out not working

Tags: android, svg, imageview

I used android-shape-imageview from this link
https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

I am able to create any type of non regular shape but Zoom in/out not working with com.meg7.widget.SvgImageView Imageview

With Normal ImageView I am able to do zoom in/out.

Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean not working? Show relevant code too.

Comment: I mean I am not able to Zoom in/out using ontouch listener. If i apply same on touch listner for simple ImageView then its working but not working with  com.meg7.widget.SvgImageView